# Is my sample suitable for elastic net? What are the assumptions?

Tags: spss, assumptions, small-sample, regularization, elastic-net

I was hoping to use multiple regression to identify significant predictors but I have a tiny sample size (group 1 n=9, group 2 n=37) so I'll be unable to do this. I have read that regularisation methods can be used with small samples. Would I be able to use elastic net or something similar? I have approx. 8 predictors but I may be able to remove some if necessary.

I apologise - my stats training is limited to two undergrad classes (covering the basics - MANOVA/ANOVA, multiple regression etc.). I've looked at a lot of resources but I haven't been able to find anything regarding the assumptions of using elastic net. I.e. can it only be used with a sample of a certain size, does the data have to be normally distributed, etc.

Also - I will be using SPSS. Can anyone direct me to some resources for running the analyses? I have found some information via statistics coach, however it doesn't explain what I should be entering as the minimum/maximum/increment values for lasso and ridge in the 'regularisation' option. I've had a practice and it also returned this error: "A regularization method has been specified, but an optimal model cannot be selected. For model selection, specify a resampling method or specify supplementary objects (test cases). Only requested regularization output will be produced".

Any advice would be dearly appreciated. I'm a little lost as to where to start.

By the way - I am looking at sleep variables predicting scores on measures of empathising and systemising in two groups of participants. I have a lot of data for each participant, however a low number of participants. If there is any other statistical analyses that I should be doing instead, I would love to hear suggestions.

Thank you for your time. I hope my post isn't too confusing!

Kindly,
Kendra.

Comment: You refer to group sizes, is your dependent variable binary or are you trying for a variant of ANCOVA?

Comment: Hi Gung. Sorry - bad choice of words. I am working with two types of participants but treating the analyses for each separately. All of my variables are continuous.